# Call to undefined method ModelReportCustomer

Tags: undefined, opencart

ok so i upgraded from opencart 1.5.3.1 to 2.0.1.1 and front end it working fine, im having an issue, however, with the admin backend. when i go the admin url it loads and allows me to input my credentials. once i do that im presented with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModelReportCustomer::getTotalCustomersOnline() in /newstaging/admin/controller/common/header.php on line 77
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

did you load the model?

```
$this->load->model('report/customer')
```

Also make sure your admin/model/report/customer.php exists